# BAM mediator not working with WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have installed the latest version of WSO2 BAM (2.4.1) and WSO2 ESB (4.8.1). The BAM Mediator in the ESB is not working. It keeps throwing the below exception everytime it tries to send a message to BAM.

Can you please help?

```
[2014-09-15 05:54:58,833] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Error occurred while finding | defining the event org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.AgentException: Cannot define type {"streamId":"TestStream:1.0.0","name":"TestsStream","version":"1.0.0","nickName":"TestStream","description":"TestStream","metaData":[{"name":"tenant_id","type":"INT"},{"name":"http_method","type":"STRING"},{"name":"character_set_encoding","type":"STRING"},{"name":"remote_address","type":"STRING"},{"name":"transport_in_url","type":"STRING"},{"name":"message_type","type":"STRING"},{"name":"remote_host","type":"STRING"},{"name":"service_prefix","type":"STRING"},{"name":"host","type":"STRING"}],"correlationData":[{"name":"activity_id","type":"STRING"}],"payloadData":
[{"name":"message_direction","type":"STRING"},{"name":"service_name","type":"STRING"},{"name":"operation_name","type":"STRING"},{"name":"message_id","type":"STRING"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"LONG"}]}
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher.defineStream(EventPublisher.java:234)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.DataPublisher.defineStream(DataPublisher.java:295)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AsyncDataPublisher$DataPublishWorker.run(AsyncDataPublisher.java:690)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.exception.EventPublisherException: TException
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.ThriftEventPublisher.defineStream(ThriftEventPublisher.java:120)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher.defineStream(EventPublisher.java:222)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:354)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:215)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.general.ThriftEventTransmissionService$Client.recv_defineStream(ThriftEventTransmissionService.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.commons.thrift.service.general.ThriftEventTransmissionService$Client.defineStream(ThriftEventTransmissionService.java:66)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.ThriftEventPublisher.defineStream(ThriftEventPublisher.java:109)
        ... 8 more
```

Thank you !

-Sarf.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify how you created the BAM server profile? If i'm not mistaken you can not specify metadata, correlation data and payload data in the BAM mediator stream.

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM241/Setting+up+BAM+Mediator